# What is the encoding method used in this string?

Tags: php, url, encoding

I am reading a documentation, but it is not specified how to encode url's. Normally, you use `urlencode`, but i don't think it is the case here. What is the encoding method used in this string :

```
http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;url.retour.com/err.cgi&#x3f;order_ref&#x3d;votreRF12345
```

**Edit:** What php method(s) sould i invoke on this string `http://url.retour.com/err.cgi?order_ref=votreRF12345` in order to encode it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This string can be decoded with [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), like this:

```
<?php
echo html_entity_decode('http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;url.retour.com/err.cgi&#x3f;order_ref&#x3d;votreRF12345');"
// output: http://url.retour.com/err.cgi?order_ref=votreRF12345
```

Answer (score 3):

It's [HTML/XML encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). The structure is `&#`, then `x` and the hex value of the Unicode codepoint (in this case identical to ASCII) and a closing `;`.

Answer (score 0):

XML Entities - x3f means char 03F UTF which is ?

Answer (score 0):

These are HTML entities. Decode them with `html_entity_decode` ([ref](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php))

In response to your edit: encode with `htmlentities` ([ref](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php))

Comment: `echo htmlentities('http://test?');` yields `'http://test?'`, even when looking at the source code of the page. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Looks like it encodes only a few chars. Look for "philsXMLClean" or a similar function in the comments page, didn't test it.

Comment: @pinouchon Why do you want to encode it this way? For HTML/XML it is sufficient to escape `&`, `<`, `"` and `>`, which is what htmlentities does.